# Renaming CoreDataGeneratedAccessors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data, entity-relationship

When I create a NSManagedObject subclass for an entity in my XCDataModel, Xcode automatically creates some accessors for to-many-relationships.

In my case, I have a tag entity that has several children.
Xcode would create these methods:

`- (void)addChildrenObject:(Tag *)value;

- (void)removeChildrenObject:(Tag *)value;

- (void)addChildren:(NSSet *)value;

- (void)removeChildren:(NSSet *)value;`

However, I'd like to rename the first two ones to addChildTag: and removeChildTag:.
Could this cause any problems because some CoreData classes expect the original ones to exist? You should know that I do not call these methods myself, I rather use the inverse relationship, which is a to-one-relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that Core Data behind the scenes actually uses these methods. I am pretty sure it depends more on primitive key-value methods e.g.`setValue:forKey`.

However, there is a lot of naming convention based functionality in the API so I could be wrong. I would suggest creating a small test project and see if you can get it to break.